# Warnings being treated as errors even though Treat all warnings as errors is unchecked

Tags: vb.net

VB.Net 2017
Winforms

I have an application with one warning that will not build. I've had this same warning in there forever "function doesn't return a value on all code paths' and it's never stopped me from building. Now... for some reason... it's stopping the build.

I checked in the project properties, Compile tab and the Treat all warnings as errors checkbox is unchecked.

Anyone have a thought?

Thank you!

Comment: "Function doesn't return a value on all code paths" doesn't sound like something that should be a *warning* that you can ignore.

Comment: Warnings do not prevent builds, errors do. Do you have any messages from the actual build in the output window you can provide all of us? If not, how about showing us that function it's complaining about...?

Comment: Icon is a yellow triangle. Message is as follows: Function GetUserData doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

Comment: Did you see my comment, `how about showing us that function it's complaining about` above? Please show the code...

Comment: @GunnerFan420 - In the Compile tab there are two specific 'Function returning...' config items.  Do they say 'Error' or 'Warn'?

Comment: Codexer the code and the function are immaterial. I'm not asking help with debugging the function I'm quite sure I can do that myself. I'm asking why a warning that's been in my project for three years is suddenly stopping the project from building.

Comment: dbasnett I don't see that on my compile tab.. if I'm looking in the right place in the project properties. I have Compile options like Option explicit (on), strict (off), compare (Binary), infer (on). Also target CPU (any cpu), Disable all warnings (unchecked), treat all warnings as errors (unchecked), Generate XML documentation file (checked).  There is small section called Warning configuration and what looks like a grid underneath but  can only see half of the top row o the grid so not sure what's there. Advanced compiler settings don't show anything like Function returning. Thank you!

Comment: In the error list there are 3 buttons (errors, warning and messages) They can be toggled. Does it say anything beside the red circle (error) like 0 of # Error (where # is a number > 0? If so, click it, you have it turned off and are not showing them in the list.

Comment: @GunnerFan420 - it is the warning configurations